# inserting data through form from one table to another

Tags: php, mysql, html, mysqli

I'm inserting values from one table to another through html form using php, but the problem is the other table is having some extra fields say my tables are

> table1(name, email, password, address, phno)

and

> table2(t_name, t_email, t_password, t_mobno, t_gender)

how to insert the `t_mobno` and `t_gender` through form same time as i'm entering the other values.

Comment: just show some codes, how you trying to achieve this

Comment: $query1="INSERT INTO table1(name, email, password, address, phno) VALUES('$name', '$emailid', '$pwd', '$addr', '$phno')";

$query2="INSERT INTO table2(t_name, t_email, t_password) SELECT  name, email, password FROM table1 WHERE email='$emailid')";

$query3=" INSERT INTO table2(t_mobno, t_gender) VALUES('$t_mobno','$t_gender') where t_email='$emailid'";    This is how i ws trying but where clause doen't works in insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer this:[INSERT INTO SELECT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp)

This Is How I Did it, might help :

```
$query = $this->db->get('Table1')->result(); // get first table
foreach($query as $result) 
{ 
//Your Post Values from form data in array : POST_DATA
$post_data = array_from_post('filed1,filed2....');

$data = array_merge($result,$post_data);

$this->db->insert('Table2', $data); // insert each row to another table
}
```

Here I have defined array_from_post in  my base model you may use it like this:

```
public function array_from_post($fields){
    $data = array();
    foreach ($fields as $field) {
        $data[$field] = $this->input->post($field);
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: sir, what about the additional fields that i have to enter through the form?

Comment: @abizz see the updated code, i have not tested but it might help you :)

Comment: @abizz maybe i got you wrong are you trying to insert data into two tables from one single form ?